# Prove that the vector space is 3D

Tags: linear-algebra

So we consider a vector space V which is defined by $f(x)=ax+be^x+csin(x)$ where a, b and c are real. I was able to prove that this was in fact a vector space in another problem that I had. Now, the problem is asking me to prove that this vector space is a space of 3 dimensions. How do you do that ? Never done this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The dimension of a vector space is equal to the number of vectors in the basis. How many vectors are in a basis of $V$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This $V$ is a subspace of the real vector space $C(\mathbb{R})$, i.e. continuous functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Now note that $V=span\{x,e^{x},\sin(x)\}$ as any member in $V$ is a unique linear combination of these vectors. These three vectors are also linearly independent so they form a basis for $V$. Implied is that $V$ has dimension $3$.

To prove that $x,e^{x},\sin(x)$ are linearly independent, consider $ax+be^{x}+c\sin(x)\equiv 0$ for some real $a,b,c$. Now this holds for all $x$, so plugging in $x=0$ gives $b=0$. Apply $b=0$ to the equation and plug in $x=\pi$ to $ax+c\sin(x)=0$ to get $a\pi=0$, i.e. $a=0$. Now finally $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$ gives $c=0$. So $a=b=c=0$, which concludes the argument.

Comment: what does "span" mean ?

Comment: The span is defined as the set of all linear combinations of the vectors given.

Comment: @copper $span\{x,e^{x},\sin(x)\}=\{ax+be^{x}+c\sin(x):a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}\}=V$ by definition of span and $V$.

Comment: So did you just choose some random values of x ? Is it possible to do this ? Just so that we can show it is linearly independent by showing that all its constants a,b,c are zeros according to some theorem I think?

Comment: @copper if $ax+be^{x}+c\sin(x)=0$ in $C(\mathbb{R})$ means that $ax+be^{x}+c\sin(x)$ is equal to the function that is zero everywhere. So this equation holds for **all** $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Now you can go ahead and choose your favorite $x$ values and plug them in to conclude that we must have $a=b=c=0$. I gave you one choice of such $x$ but there are plenty of other options for this.

Comment: Ok, last question. The only part I dont understand is when I prove they are independant, how does this conclude its 3d ? Is there a theorem about this ?

Comment: @copper. Look up the definition for dimension. The dimension of a vector space is defined as the number of linearly independent vectors that spans it.

Comment: Oh, yeah I just noticed this now. Then everything is clear, thanks again!

Comment: @copper. Great! you're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You need to show that your three functions are linearly independent.

That is $ax + be^x + c\sin x = 0 \iff a,b,c = 0$

To do that, choose some values for $x$.  This simplifies your problem to a system of linear equations, and it should be easy enough to show that the only solution is $a,b,c =0$

Comment: The only thing I dont undesrtand is how does proving that they are independent tells me its 3d ? Is there some theorem about this that I forgot ?

Comment: You have 3 independent "vectors", and that makes for a 3D space.